# swift 5 abstract network response with codable array

Tags: swift, codable

I have a model `Employee` & `Office`:

```
struct Employee: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}
struct Office: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

On request employee or office body of request:

```
{
  total: Int
  rows: [Employee]
}
or
{
  total: Int
  rows: [Office]
}
```

And for it I want to create abstract model like:

```
struct NetworkResponse: Codable {
    let rows: [Codable]
    let total: Int
}
```

But it throws error:

> Type 'NetworkResponse' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

> Type 'NetworkResponse' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

> Cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because '[Decodable]' does not conform to 'Decodable'

How can I create abstract respons model for any response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use generics:

```
struct NetworkResponse<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let rows: [T]
    let total: Int
}

typealias EmployeeResponse = NetworkResponse<Employee>
typealias OfficeReponse = NetworkResponse<Office>
```